# UITabBarController show views only if logged in

Tags: ios, authentication, uitabbarcontroller

I'm creating an app with a `UITabBarController` and a login system.

Certain tabs (views) in the `UITabBarController` should only be available if a user is logged in.

```
if(loggedIn) {
    //Show 5 tabs
}else{
    //Show 3 Tabs
}
```

How could I make something like this with a `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restricting which tabs are selectable, is achieved by setting a delegate of the UITabBarController (i.e. one that conforms to UITabBarControllerDelegate).

In the delegate, you should implement these two methods:

– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:

– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:

Returning valid values depending on log in status.